# warning: passing argument 1 of 'fprintf' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, file

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'fprintf' from incompatible pointer type 
warning: passing argument 2 of 'fprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

How can I fix these two warnings? I cannot produce a file with expected output.

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int num_values = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    value_t* pValues = generate_sequence(num_values);

    randomize_sequence(pValues, num_values);

    // Record results
    //FILE *fd = fopen("/results.txt", "w+");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++) { //change made: i++ to allow looping
        fprintf("results.txt", i, pValues[i]); //changes made: "fprintf". i and fd were added to the argument
    }
    //fclose(fd); //change made: "fclose"

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: fprintf -> printf

Comment: You need to pass fd to fprintf instead of the file name or use printf as suggested by S.M.

Comment: `fprintf` does not take a file name. Suggest you read the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf), go thru a basic C tutorial and do basic research by searching.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/62804356/2410359  I suspect will get a 3rd post after this.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `fprintf` should be the `FILE*` that is returned from a call to `fopen`.

The second argument is a format string. Any further arguments are inserted into the placeholders in the format string.

Consider reading the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) to better understand standard library functions.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax for `fprintf()` is

> `int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)`

Where first argument `FILE *stream` needs a file pointer, which should be opened for operation using

> `FILE *fptr = fopen("results.txt", "w");`

function.

So, please uncomment line no. 54 and 58 then inside loop change the `fprintf("results.txt", i, pValues[i])` to `fprintf(fd, "%d", pValues[i])`.

Also learn about [Basics of File Handling in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basics-file-handling-c/).